# Classification of singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As part of a practice question sheet I have been asked to determine the singular points of several differential equations as well as classify them as a regular or irregular singular point. I understand that a point is regular if $(x-x0)P(x)$ and $(x-x0)^2Q(x)$ are analytic at $x0$ for some differential equation $y'' + P(x)y'+y = 0$. However, I am struggling to understand what it means for a function to be analytic and how to find these points.  An example of a question for which I have to find the singular points and classify them is:
$$x^3y''+4x^2y'+3y = 0$$
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $x=0$ is a singular and irregular point.

Comment: Would you be able to explain to me how you came to that answer?

Comment: Divide by $x^3$ your DE.... Then you have that the coefficients of y is $3/x^3$ Calculate now $x^2(3/x^3)$ you get $3/x$ this has a singularity at $x=0$ so it's an irregular singular point.